# Battery started to draing too quickly after battery health got down to 99%

Tags: battery, apple-silicon, sonoma

I have an MBP with M2 Pro chip almost a year old. I tried to save my battery health as much as I could. Lately I was experiencing my battery draining much faster than before so I checked my battery settings to see its health is down to 99%. I'm pretty sure that %1 health change should not affect my experience this much; like 30% less usage than before. Even while I'm typing this question, battery percentage got down 5%; 96 to 91. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you examined the Energy tab in Activity Monitor? Refer to both the "Energy Inpact" column and look for unusually high values. Currently on my system all applications are reading <100. The "12-hr Power" column gives you longer term averages

Comment: As I expected Xcode consumes the most of the energy; values around 40 - 60. But I  am working on the same project for moths, so I would not expect this consumption was different before and should not be the reason of the problem I am experiencing